# Create csv of children records on parent in master-detail relationship

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, master-detail, roll-up-summary

I have a `Master-Detail` Relationship.
Each Child record has a `Name__c` field.

I want to create a `child_names__c` field on Parent that is a sorted-asc csv of of each Child's `Name`.

`Rollup-summary` seems to only allow me to operate on Numeric fields and not `Text`.
I can't use a `Formula` Field either because I can't operate on Children records.

What's the best way to do something like this? A Flow for each time a Child record is modified?

I'd have to recalculate this `child_names__c` field any time any of the child records are either added,removed,updated. This is because I need to maintain the sorted csv.

In JS, I'd do something like `const childNames = Parent.getChildren().map(child => child.name).sort().join(",")`  any time there's a `CRUD` operation on a `Child`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This can be done in [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) as it supports a concatenation operator

Comment: worked like a charm after some trial+error. Pretty self-explanatory plugin too. I can accept this as an answer if you would like. 

Will have to thoroughly test this to see how performant it is though. I'm upserting 50k+ records once a day and the new rollup-summary will have to be run for any related parent records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cool tool to use for rollups when OOTB roll-up summaries aren't applicable is [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (open source).

In addition to working over lookup relationships, it supports expanded summarization operators. For you, the relevant one is [concatenation](https://andrewfawcett.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/textrollup.png) including [delimiter configuration](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/02/16/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries-tool-dlrs-spring15-release/).

You'll need to be cognizant of the parent field size (for example, if there were 1000 child rows for a given parent, each with a text field of length 133, then you'd exceed the maximum field size for a text area long field.

DLRS supports real-time rollups as well as scheduled rollups (as a batch).

Comment: "You'll need to be cognizant of the parent field size"..good point. I'm going with `Text Long` for Parent field to account for this